# Как создать подписку событий командой powershell

Tags: windows, события, powershell, active-directory

Как я могу создать подписку на перенаправленные события командой powershell в windows/winserver.

Мне нужна команда, которая в разделе "Просмотр событий" -> подписки ... создаст подписку, где я могу указать параметры по типу тех, что на скриншоте ниже (это графическое управление подписками, нужно командное)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: первый же запрос поисковика выдал: [Централизованный сбор логов](https://www.mytechnote.ru/article/centralizovannyy-sbor-logov-v-windows-s-raznyh-kompyuterov-shtatnymi-sredstvami)

Comment: Не вижу, чтобы в данной статье был пример того, как программно создать подписку. Вручную я умею создавать, мне нужна команда или любой программный способ, который даст мне автоматически выполнить то, что вручную делается на скриншоте выше

Comment: Тогда  можно взять инструкции [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wec/creating-an-event-collector-subscription) и автоматизировать процесс. Судя по мануалам, конфигурирование не требует средств GUI, а использует встроенные утилиты (которые можно вызывать тем же Powershell).

Comment: А вот это уже похоже на правду, да, экзешник си++  можно стартануть из павершел) Спасибо, буду разбираться, пару строк кода